# Display two keys for cell from Parse database Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, key

I want to grab both "firstName" and "lastName" key attributes and display it in a cell. Here's what I have:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.parseClassName = "User"
    //Right now, it'll only display the first name
    self.textKey = "firstName"
}

override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    let query = PFUser.query()

    query?.whereKey("firstName", containsString: searchString)
    return query
}
```

How can I store a variable that has both "firstName" and "lastName" attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You do it in the tableview delegate method.

```
 override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

  var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! PFTableViewCell!


  if cell == nil {


    cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
  }
  // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell

  if let customerFirstName = object?["FirstName"] as? String {
    cell?.textLabel?.text = customerFirstName
  }

  if let customerLastName = object?["customerLastName"] as? String {
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = customerStreetAddress
    }

  return cell
```

}
Click on the cell for the tableview and go over to the inspector pain and change the style to "Subtitle"

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. However, for detailTextLabel, I don't have a second label, and thus it's only showing the first name.

Comment: i updated the answer for you so it will display the detail text/subtitle

Comment: Sorry for such a late response. It doesn't seem like the detail label is being shown in my table view.